# Plot the boxplot by using check box in shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'd like to use check box input to allow to show different island levels (within the categorical variable selected for the x-axis) with separate boxplots and different colors with a legend. But if this check box is not selected, I just want to show boxplot without fill=legend that is:

```
ggplot(dat(), aes_string(x = isolate(input$xaxis), y = input$yaxis)) +
            geom_boxplot()
```

This R code is what I tried to use but It didn't work. Could you please help me to solve or tell me what makes error with my R code?
Thank you in advance

```
library(shiny)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

penguin <- penguins

penguin$year <- as.factor(penguin$year)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Data Visualisation of Penguins Data"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("yaxis",
                label = "Choose a y-axis variable to display",
                choices = list("bill_length_mm",
                               "bill_depth_mm",
                               "flipper_length_mm",
                               "body_mass_g"),
                selected = "bill_length_mm"),
    selectInput("xaxis",
                label = "Choose a x-axis variable to display",
                choices = c("species",
                            "sex",
                            "year"),
                selected = "sex"),
    checkboxGroupInput("islandlevels",
                       label = "Check to display different island levels",
                       choices = c("island"),
                       selected = NULL),
    br(), br(),
    selectInput("species",
                label = "Choose species to view separate plot",
                choices = list("Adelie",
                               "Chinstrap",
                               "Gentoo"),
                selected = NULL)),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1"),
    br(), br(),
    plotOutput("plot2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  dat <- reactive({
    if(input$xaxis == "sex") penguin[!is.na(penguin$sex),] else penguin
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    if(input$islandlevels == "island") {
      req(penguin, input$xaxis, input$yaxis)
      ggplot(dat(), aes_string(x = isolate(input$xaxis), y = input$yaxis, fill=island)) +
        geom_boxplot()
    }
    if(input$islandlevels = NULL) {
      req(penguin, input$xaxis, input$yaxis) 
          ggplot(dat(), aes_string(x = isolate(input$xaxis), y = input$yaxis)) +
            geom_boxplot()}
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As long as you don't want any other checkbox inputs you could use a `checkboxInput` instead of a `checkboxGroupInput` which makes checking a bit easier.
2. One issue in your server was that you used `island` instead of `"island"`. Additionally you can simplify your code a little bit by using `fill <- if (input$islandlevels) "island"` which will return `NULL` is the the checkbox was not checked and `"island"` otherwise. This way you can handle both case with only one `ggplot` statement .

The full reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

penguin <- penguins

penguin$year <- as.factor(penguin$year)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Data Visualisation of Penguins Data"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("yaxis",
                label = "Choose a y-axis variable to display",
                choices = list("bill_length_mm",
                               "bill_depth_mm",
                               "flipper_length_mm",
                               "body_mass_g"),
                selected = "bill_length_mm"),
    selectInput("xaxis",
                label = "Choose a x-axis variable to display",
                choices = c("species",
                            "sex",
                            "year"),
                selected = "sex"),
    checkboxInput("islandlevels",
                       label = "Check to display different island levels",
                       value = FALSE),
    br(), br(),
    selectInput("species",
                label = "Choose species to view separate plot",
                choices = list("Adelie",
                               "Chinstrap",
                               "Gentoo"),
                selected = NULL)),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1"),
    br(), br(),
    plotOutput("plot2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  dat <- reactive({
    if(input$xaxis == "sex") penguin[!is.na(penguin$sex),] else penguin
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(penguin, input$xaxis, input$yaxis) 
    fill <- if (input$islandlevels) "island"
    ggplot(dat(), aes_string(x = isolate(input$xaxis), y = input$yaxis, fill = fill)) +
        geom_boxplot()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: if we wanted the `checkboxInput` to depend on the `species` `selectInput` selection (instead of `island`), how would you do that? I thought I could change the line `fill <- if (input$islandlevels) "island"` to  `fill <- if (input$islandlevels) input$species` but it doesn't seem to work, cheers

Comment: Hi @user63230. Actually the `selectInput` for species has no effect in the example code. If you want the fill color by `species` use `if (input$islandlevels) "species"`, i..e use the name of the column you want to map on `fill`. If you want to get a separate boxplot for the selected species you could use `if (input$islandlevels) "species == input$species"`.

Comment: thats really helpful, thank you. FInal question, if we wanted a separate boxplot by a variable instead of selected species, what would the `if` statement look like? E.g. if we change selectInput to: `selectInput("variableselection", label = "Choose variable to view separate boxplot", choices = c("species",  "island"), selected = "species"))`, I tried: `fill <- if (input$islandlevels) "input$variableselection"` but it doesnt work?

Comment: (: Not tested but in that case you could do `fill <- if (input$islandlevels) input$variableselection` as `input$variableselection` is already a character string containing the column name.